# Using mathematical induction to show $\log(n) \leq \log(2n)$

Tags: inequality, induction

Using the principle of mathematical induction, 
prove that $\log(1) \leq \log(2) \leq \log(n) \leq \log(2n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: $log(2)\le log(n)$ is false for $n=1$. Rather than using induction, you can proof the inequalities by using the monotony of the $\ln$-function and the rule $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$

Comment: Let $f(x)=\log x - \log 2x$. Then it is easy to see that $f'(x)=0 \forall x  > 0$. What does this tell you in context of your original question?

Answer (score 1):

$\text{log} (2) = \text{log}(2 \times 1) = \text{log} (1) + \text{log}(2) \geq \text{log}(1)$

$\text{log} (2n) = \text{log}(2 \times n) = \text{log}(2) + \text{log}(n) \geq \text{log}(n)$

(Given the base is $> 1$)

In general:
$\text{log}(2) \text{ is not} \leq \text{log}(n)$

Comment: @DonAntonio Corrected the answer to remove 1 as a possible base. Thanks.